# When case update query in zend framework

Tags: mysql, zend-framework, pdo

Here is my mysql query

```
UPDATE uss20_prj_avunea.tbl_loc_images SET img_sortorder = CASE img_id WHEN 210 THEN 1 WHEN 211 THEN 2 WHEN 67 THEN 3 WHEN 62 THEN 4 WHEN 207 THEN 5 WHEN 208 THEN 6 WHEN 209 THEN 7 END WHERE img_id IN ( 210, 211, 67, 62, 207, 208, 209 )
```

I have dynamic image id group it can be increase or decrease 
anyone can help me to create zend pdo for above mysql query

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try it this way:

```
UPDATE uss20_prj_avunea.tbl_loc_images SET img_sortorder = 
(SELECT CASE WHEN img_id = 210 THEN 1 
WHEN img_id = 211 THEN 2 
WHEN img_id = 67 THEN 3 
WHEN img_id = 62 THEN 4 
WHEN img_id = 207 THEN 5 
WHEN img_id = 208 THEN 6
WHEN img_id = 209 THEN 7 END from tbl_loc_images)
WHERE img_id IN ( 210, 211, 67, 62, 207, 208, 209)
```

Not tested yet.

I think it returns an error cause you need only only record SET img_sortorder. You can try it to limit 1 if worked.

Answer (score 1):

new \Zend\Db\Sql\Expression(CASE img_id WHEN 210 THEN 1 WHEN 211 THEN 2 WHEN 67 THEN 3 WHEN 62 THEN 4 WHEN 207 THEN 5 WHEN 208 THEN 6 WHEN 209 THEN 7 END )
WHERE img_id IN ( 210, 211, 67, 62, 207, 208, 209 )

Use Zf2 expression for this. Hope it will help you.